# compiles on overleaf but not local

Tags: texlive, compiling, overleaf

I have successfully compiled my document on Overleaf, but I cannot get it to compile on my local Windows machine. I have installed TeXLive, and tried 1) TexStudio 2) TexWorks and 3) the powershell.

Every time, it hangs on this line:
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1phv.fd)

Is there something wrong with my TexLive installation?  I did not see any error messages during the installation, but it took about 6 hours, so I could have missed something..

EDIT: I am not sure what code exactly to put on here, but a warning is that there is no file filename.aux .

```
> pdflatex filename.tex
```

Then it hangs on

```
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1phv.fd)
```

When I pressed Ctrl+C in the powershell , this is what I got:

```
 \citep{name_of_my_first_reference}

\org@@citex ...fe@activesfalse \org@@citex [#1][#2
                                                 ]{@tempa } 
?
```

I am quite new to local latex, I have only ever used Overleaf.  The problem is, when answering to reviewers, I need to have a 'tracked changes' document.  I could not find a solution for this in Overleaf, only something like latexdiff, which exists in local latex .

Thanks for any advice and please let me know what other information that would be useful?

My full log output:

```
> pdflatex filename.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./filename.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-02-18> (./copernicus.cls
Document Class: copernicus 2020/06/24 9.11 Copernicus papers
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fixltx2e.sty

Package fixltx2e Warning: fixltx2e is not required with releases after 2015
(fixltx2e)                All fixes are now in the LaTeX kernel.
(fixltx2e)                See the latexrelease package for details.

)
Additional configuration file copernicus.cfg used
(./copernicus.cfg) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fleqn.clo)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ulem/ulem.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/xmltex/passivetex/ucharacters.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/array.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/tabularx.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amscls/amsthm.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/accents/accents.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/cancel/cancel.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/multirow/multirow.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithmic.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/algorithms/algorithm.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/float/float.sty))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)

Package caption Warning: Unknown document class (or package),
(caption)                standard defaults will be used.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.

) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/subfloat/subfloat.sty
Package `subfloat', Version 2.14 of 2003/08/21.

Package subfloat Warning: Numbers of floats not counted:
(subfloat)                If you use one of the counters subfloatfiguremax or
(subfloat)                subfloattablemax you will get strange error messages
(subfloat)                containing \c@subfloatfiguremax or
(subfloat)                \c@subfloattablemax:
(subfloat)                Please switch on countmax or remove the code using
(subfloat)                the counter then..

) (./natbib.sty) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/rotating.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lineno/lineno.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/times.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/pifont.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upzd.fd)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/upsy.fd))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/kvdefinekeys/kvdefinekeys.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdfescape/pdfescape.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hycolor/hycolor.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/letltxmacro/letltxmacro.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/auxhook/auxhook.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/pd1enc.def)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref-langpatches.def)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/intcalc/intcalc.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/etexcmds/etexcmds.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/puenc.def)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bitset/bitset.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/bigintcalc/bigintcalc.sty))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atbegshi-ltx.sty))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hpdftex.def
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/atveryend-ltx.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/rerunfilecheck/rerunfilecheck.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/uniquecounter/uniquecounter.sty))))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1ptm.fd)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file filename.aux.
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/nameref.sty
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcount/refcount.sty)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/generic/gettitlestring/gettitlestring.sty))
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsa.fd)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/umsb.fd)
(c:/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/t1phv.fd)
```

Comment: You need to give at least some information to allow someone to help. The line you show is a standard logging of the font definition file for helvetica, and the fact that it ends with `)` means that the file was read to the end with no issues. If TeX hangs after that some code in your document after that point is looping but what that loop is we can not guess.

Comment: @WillieWong ok, i did not know that line was 'totally useless' for troubleshooting, and have pasted more lines.

Comment: On the Overleaf document where it compiles, can you go to the overleaf menu (top left button), and report back which compiler and texlive version Overleaf is using?

Comment: compiler: pdfLaTeX ,  TeXLive version:  2019.  Could this error be caused from using the 2020 on my local and 2019 on overleaf? EDIT:  I compiled it using 2020 on Overleaf, then downloaded the zip file and tried to compile it on the local.  It is the same log file and hangs in the same place.

Comment: Overleaf uses the <2020-02-02> release of LaTeX; your installed one is <2020-10-01>; there were some significant changes to the TeX kernel last october that resulted in breakages of many packages across the board.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for the information.  Should I un-install my current version of TexLive and re-install an older one?

Comment: Try this: I just noticed that on copernicus.org they pushed a newer version of the document class; the current one is version 9.25 from 2021/01/12; you are using the copernicus.cls file from 2020/06/24. It is possible that the new version may have fixed something. (Even though their website says it is January 15, 2020, the package is actually newer.)

Comment: that worked, i will be sure to check versions of cls files in the future but i think it is hard to find this information unless someone tells you (for a newcomer to latex like me).  If you want you can add it in the answer and I would accept it thanks for your help

Comment: "I think it is hard to find this information unless someone tells you"; this is pretty much why this website exists. This is especially hard for third-party document classes like copernicus which is not maintained on CTAN and does not get updated automatically. I think the real takeaway message for you is to always paste the full log the next time your ask a question. Someone with a bit of experience may notice things in it that you would find innocuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that updating to the newest version of the `copernicus.cls` document class (version 9.25 from 2021/01/12) can resolve this issue.

Based on the fact that the older document class compiles fine on TeXLive 2019 and on the February 2020 release of TeXLive, I suspect the issue has to do with one of the changes made in the Oct 2020 TeXLive Release.