# Same code compiles in Overleaf, but not on my machine

Tags: overleaf

So I've been having some difficulty implementing a glossary, so I copied the bare minimum code from [here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries), but it didn't compile properly on my machine.

It finished compiling and looked fine, but there was no glossary. On Overleaf, that same code is fine. The log is different though (not sure if that's relevant).

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/587963/compiles-on-overleaf-but-not-local) answer suggests it might be the version that I'm running. I changed Overleaf to the 2019 version that I've got, and it compiled fine, and showed the glossary in the final product.

How is this possible?

Code:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Welcome to Overleaf --- just edit your LaTeX on the left,
% and we'll compile it for you on the right. If you open the
% 'Share' menu, you can invite other users to edit at the same
% time. See www.overleaf.com/learn for more info. Enjoy!
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{latex}
{
    name=latex,
    description={Is a markup language specially suited 
    for scientific documents}
}

\newglossaryentry{maths}
{
    name=mathematics,
    description={Mathematics is what mathematicians do}
}

\title{How to create a glossary}
\author{ }
\date{ }

\begin{document}
\maketitle

The \Gls{latex} typesetting markup language is specially suitable 
for documents that include \gls{maths}. 

\clearpage

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

My Log

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/Debian) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2022.8.11)  16 OCT 2022 23:19
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**test.tex
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2020-02-14>
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty
Package: glossaries 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count175
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty
Package: mfirstuc 2017/11/14 v2.06 (NLCT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count176
)
\@glsmfirst=\toks18
\@glsmrest=\toks19
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty
Package: xfor 2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty
Package: datatool-base 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2020/01/20 v2.17e AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip49

For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks20
\ex@=\dimen135
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen136
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count177
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 227.
\uproot@=\count178
\leftroot@=\count179
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 389.
\classnum@=\count180
\DOTSCASE@=\count181
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 486.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 489.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 610.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box45
\strutbox@=\box46
\big@size=\dimen137
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 733.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 734.
\macc@depth=\count182
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count183
\dotsspace@=\muskip16
\c@parentequation=\count184
\dspbrk@lvl=\count185
\tag@help=\toks21
\row@=\count186
\column@=\count187
\maxfields@=\count188
\andhelp@=\toks22
\eqnshift@=\dimen138
\alignsep@=\dimen139
\tagshift@=\dimen140
\tagwidth@=\dimen141
\totwidth@=\dimen142
\lineht@=\dimen143
\@envbody=\toks23
\multlinegap=\skip50
\multlinetaggap=\skip51
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks24
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2859.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2860.
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty
Package: substr 2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
\c@su@anzahl=\count189
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty
Package: datatool-fp 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
Package: fp 1995/04/02

`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty
Package: defpattern 1994/10/12
\actioncount=\count190
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty
Package: fp-basic 1996/05/13
\FP@xs=\count191
\FP@xia=\count192
\FP@xib=\count193
\FP@xfa=\count194
\FP@xfb=\count195
\FP@rega=\count196
\FP@regb=\count197
\FP@regs=\count198
\FP@times=\count199
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty
Package: fp-addons 1995/03/15
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty
Package: fp-snap 1995/04/05
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty
Package: fp-exp 1995/04/03
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty
Package: fp-trigo 1995/04/14
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty
Package: fp-pas 1994/08/29
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty
Package: fp-random 1995/02/23
\FPseed=\count266
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty
Package: fp-eqn 1995/04/03
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty
Package: fp-upn 1996/10/21
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty
Package: fp-eval 1995/04/03
)))
\@dtl@toks=\toks25
\@dtl@tmpcount=\count267
\dtl@tmplength=\skip52
\dtl@sortresult=\count268
\@dtl@numgrpsepcount=\count269
\@dtl@datatype=\count270
\dtl@codeA=\count271
\dtl@codeB=\count272
\@dtl@foreach@level=\count273
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-
307.sty
Package: glossaries-compatible-307 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)
)
\gls@level=\count274
\@gls@tmpb=\toks26
\gls@tmplen=\skip53
\glskeylisttok=\toks27
\glslabeltok=\toks28
\glsshorttok=\toks29
\glslongtok=\toks30

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.st
y
Package: glossary-hypernav 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty
Package: glossary-list 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)
\glslistdottedwidth=\skip54
) (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty
Package: glossary-long 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2020/01/07 v4.13 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip55
\LTright=\skip56
\LTpre=\skip57
\LTpost=\skip58
\LTchunksize=\count275
\LTcapwidth=\dimen144
\LT@head=\box47
\LT@firsthead=\box48
\LT@foot=\box49
\LT@lastfoot=\box50
\LT@cols=\count276
\LT@rows=\count277
\c@LT@tables=\count278
\c@LT@chunks=\count279
\LT@p@ftn=\toks31
)
\glsdescwidth=\skip59
\glspagelistwidth=\skip60
)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty
Package: glossary-super 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty
Package: supertabular 2020/02/02 v4.1g the supertabular environment
\c@tracingst=\count280
\ST@wd=\dimen145
\ST@rightskip=\skip61
\ST@leftskip=\skip62
\ST@parfillskip=\skip63
\ST@pageleft=\dimen146
\ST@headht=\dimen147
\ST@tailht=\dimen148
\ST@pagesofar=\dimen149
\ST@pboxht=\dimen150
\ST@lineht=\dimen151
\ST@prevht=\dimen152
\ST@toadd=\dimen153
\ST@dimen=\dimen154
\ST@pbox=\box51
))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty
Package: glossary-tree 2020/02/13 v4.45 (NLCT)
\glstreeindent=\skip64
))
\glswrite=\write3
\glo@main@file=\write4
\openout4 = `test.glo'.

Package glossaries Info: Writing glossary file test.glo on input line 13.

(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-02-03 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count281
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box52
)
No file test.aux.
\openout1 = `test.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
[1

\openout3 = `test.ist'.

{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
No file test.gls.
[2

] (./test.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 5102 strings out of 481239
 76214 string characters out of 5920377
 367359 words of memory out of 5000000
 20308 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 536047 words of font info for 37 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 51i,4n,39p,984b,187s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mr10.pfb></usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pf
b>
Output written on test.pdf (2 pages, 25239 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 19 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 12 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Overleaf's Log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.12.13)  16 OCT 2022 22:29
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(/compile/main.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
Package: inputenc 2018/08/11 v1.3c Input encoding file
\inpenc@prehook=\toks14
\inpenc@posthook=\toks15
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries.sty
Package: glossaries 2019/09/28 v4.43 (NLCT)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks16
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks17
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count88
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mfirstuc/mfirstuc.sty
Package: mfirstuc 2017/11/14 v2.06 (NLCT)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2019/09/21 v2.5h e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count89
)
\@glsmfirst=\toks18
\@glsmrest=\toks19
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/textcase/textcase.sty
Package: textcase 2019/09/14 v1.00 Text only upper/lower case changing (DPC)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xfor/xfor.sty
Package: xfor 2009/02/05 v1.05 (NLCT)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-base.sty
Package: datatool-base 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2019/11/16 v2.17d AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks20
\ex@=\dimen103
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen104
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count90
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 227.
\uproot@=\count91
\leftroot@=\count92
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 389.
\classnum@=\count93
\DOTSCASE@=\count94
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 486.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 489.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 610.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box27
\strutbox@=\box28
\big@size=\dimen105
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 733.
LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 734.
\macc@depth=\count95
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count96
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count97
\dspbrk@lvl=\count98
\tag@help=\toks21
\row@=\count99
\column@=\count100
\maxfields@=\count101
\andhelp@=\toks22
\eqnshift@=\dimen106
\alignsep@=\dimen107
\tagshift@=\dimen108
\tagwidth@=\dimen109
\totwidth@=\dimen110
\lineht@=\dimen111
\@envbody=\toks23
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks24
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2858.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2859.
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/substr/substr.sty
Package: substr 2009/10/20 v1.2 Handle substrings
\c@su@anzahl=\count102
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/datatool/datatool-fp.sty
Package: datatool-fp 2019/09/27 v2.32 (NLCT)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp.sty
Package: fp 1995/04/02
`Fixed Point Package', Version 0.8, April 2, 1995 (C) Michael Mehlich (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/defpattern.sty
Package: defpattern 1994/10/12
\actioncount=\count103
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-basic.sty
Package: fp-basic 1996/05/13
\FP@xs=\count104
\FP@xia=\count105
\FP@xib=\count106
\FP@xfa=\count107
\FP@xfb=\count108
\FP@rega=\count109
\FP@regb=\count110
\FP@regs=\count111
\FP@times=\count112
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-addons.sty
Package: fp-addons 1995/03/15
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-snap.sty
Package: fp-snap 1995/04/05
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-exp.sty
Package: fp-exp 1995/04/03
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-trigo.sty
Package: fp-trigo 1995/04/14
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-pas.sty
Package: fp-pas 1994/08/29
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-random.sty
Package: fp-random 1995/02/23
\FPseed=\count113
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eqn.sty
Package: fp-eqn 1995/04/03
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-upn.sty
Package: fp-upn 1996/10/21
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fp/fp-eval.sty
Package: fp-eval 1995/04/03
)))
\@dtl@toks=\toks25
\@dtl@tmpcount=\count114
\dtl@tmplength=\skip46
\dtl@sortresult=\count115
\@dtl@numgrpsepcount=\count116
\@dtl@datatype=\count117
\dtl@codeA=\count118
\dtl@codeB=\count119
\@dtl@foreach@level=\count120
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/base/glossaries-compatible-307.sty
Package: glossaries-compatible-307 2019/09/28 v4.43 (NLCT)
)
\gls@level=\count121
\@gls@tmpb=\toks26
\gls@tmplen=\skip47
\glskeylisttok=\toks27
\glslabeltok=\toks28
\glsshorttok=\toks29
\glslongtok=\toks30
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-hypernav.sty
Package: glossary-hypernav 2019/09/28 v4.43 (NLCT)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-list.sty
Package: glossary-list 2019/09/28 v4.43 (NLCT)
\glslistdottedwidth=\skip48
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-long.sty
Package: glossary-long 2019/09/28 v4.43 (NLCT)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/longtable.sty
Package: longtable 2019/02/06 v4.12 Multi-page Table package (DPC)
\LTleft=\skip49
\LTright=\skip50
\LTpre=\skip51
\LTpost=\skip52
\LTchunksize=\count122
\LTcapwidth=\dimen112
\LT@head=\box29
\LT@firsthead=\box30
\LT@foot=\box31
\LT@lastfoot=\box32
\LT@cols=\count123
\LT@rows=\count124
\c@LT@tables=\count125
\c@LT@chunks=\count126
\LT@p@ftn=\toks31
)
\glsdescwidth=\skip53
\glspagelistwidth=\skip54
) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-super.sty
Package: glossary-super 2019/09/28 v4.43 (NLCT)
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/supertabular/supertabular.sty
Package: supertabular 2004/02/20 v4.1e the supertabular environment
\c@tracingst=\count127
\ST@wd=\dimen113
\ST@rightskip=\skip55
\ST@leftskip=\skip56
\ST@parfillskip=\skip57
\ST@pageleft=\dimen114
\ST@headht=\dimen115
\ST@tailht=\dimen116
\ST@pagesofar=\dimen117
\ST@pboxht=\dimen118
\ST@lineht=\dimen119
\ST@stretchht=\dimen120
\ST@prevht=\dimen121
\ST@toadd=\dimen122
\ST@dimen=\dimen123
\ST@pbox=\box33
)) (/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/glossaries/styles/glossary-tree.sty
Package: glossary-tree 2019/09/28 v4.43 (NLCT)
\glstreeindent=\skip58
))
\glswrite=\write3
\glo@main@file=\write4
\openout4 = `output.glo'.

Package glossaries Info: Writing glossary file output.glo on input line 13.
(/compile/output.aux)
\openout1 = `output.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 32.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 32.
[1

\openout3 = `output.ist'.

{/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (/compile/output.gls) [2

] (/compile/output.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 4951 strings out of 492164
 72538 string characters out of 6125314
 193148 words of memory out of 5000000
 9251 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 8262 words of font info for 30 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 50i,4n,39p,1969b,215s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr17.pfb>
Output written on /compile/output.pdf (2 pages, 45531 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 27 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 18 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: did you run makeglossaries locally?

Comment: you need to run makeglossaries then pdflatex twice more

Comment: OK. So that worked. Would have been useful for that article to mention this. By the way, I needed to first run pdflatex (to get an .aux file), then makeglossaries, then pdflatex again.